# Table lines (vertical/horizontal) not meeting up

Tags: tables

First of all, I tried searching Tex.SX for this, and didn't find an answer, but did find lots of people saying not to use vertical lines.  That part, for me, is not up for discussion, as I must fit in many columns.  My only concern is that my uppermost horizontal rule does not quite meet up with my vertical line on the left side.  There is the tiniest of gaps that is bugging me.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{1mm}}|}
\cline{3-20}
&&\multicolumn{18}{c|}{Heading}\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}stuff-\\stuff\end{tabular}}}&stuff1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff2&&&&&&&&&&A&&&&&B&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&C&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff4&D&&&&&E&&&&&&&F&&G&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&H&&&&&&&&I&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Table for stuff}
\label{table6}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is what the output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is `@{\hspace{1mm}}`. I'm not sure why the `cline` is shifted on the one side and not the other, though. In either case, you can use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}` inside your table (outside your tabular environment) to set the minimum horizontal space on either side of column separators instead of defining them individually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{3-20}
&&\multicolumn{18}{c|}{Heading}\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}stuff-\\stuff\end{tabular}}}&stuff1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff2&&&&&&&&&&A&&&&&B&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&C&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-20}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&stuff4&D&&&&&E&&&&&&&F&&G&&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&&H&&&&&&&&I&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Table for stuff}
\label{table6}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Using 1mm space on both sides of the vertical lines]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to construct that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{20}{l}}[corners=NW,vlines]
\Hline
&&\Block{1-18}{Heading}\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
\Hline
\Hline
\Block{8-1}{stuff-\\stuff}%
&stuff1\\
\\
\Hline
&stuff2&&&&&&&&&&A&&&&&B\\
&&&&&C\\
\Hline
&stuff3\\
\\
\Hline
&stuff4&D&&&&&E&&&&&&&F&&G\\
&&H&&&&&&&&I\\
\Hline
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Table for stuff}
\label{table6}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]